# I have volatility of a portfolio in year 1 and in year 2. How do I calculate the volatility over the total 2-year period?

Tags: volatility, portfolio, time

thanks for looking into this question. See the picture below (better is right-mousebutton - open in new tab). I also have the price and return data of the Stocks if that's needed to calculate the total 2-year period volatility. 

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's  an additive  process so you will get the variance of year one and multiple  by number of trading  days divided  by 256, do the same for year  2 , sum the results  and the  take  it to the power of (512/total  number of trading  days)

Comment: There  is a different  but  let's  keep it simple

Comment: Thanks a lot Tulio! If I could I would definitely vote this answer up. I'm wondering however, why you divide number of annual trading days by 256, and then use the value of 512 in the power? I now do achieve the right answer but don't know how to change the formula.. I also for example like to know the portfolio volatility for the period ranging from Mar2012-Feb 2014, if I have volatility from Mar-Dec 2012, whole 2013, and Jan-Feb 2014. Can you elaborate the formula a little bit more? Thanks a lot you've been a great help already!

Comment: 256 in some measure  is the business business days in a year. The reason  you take to the power of that expression  is to have volatility  measured  in years

Comment: Thanks Tulio! I know see that I can apply this to certain subperiods within years as well.. You've saved me for a finance paper I have to write (3rd year economics) - I could only find wrong methods through googling